# how does [[ ]] work in for loop in r?

Tags: r, loops

I have these codes from maxstat function source code :

```
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  mmax[[i]] <- cmaxstat(scores, x[, i], weights = weights, 
    pmethod = pmethod, minprop = minprop, maxprop = maxprop, 
    alpha = alpha, ...)
  mmax[[i]]$data.name <- colnames(x)[i]
```

I know [ ] means index but, I can't find that [[ ]] works in that code. 
If you know, please explain how does it work.

In imagine, if ncol(x)=2, data sets, mmax1 and mmax2, are created?

Comment: The easiest is to read the help page: `?"[["`.

Comment: If you are looking for something a bit more verbose, read this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: Lists are easy. https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136

Comment: `[[` works exactly in the same way inside a loop as outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that `mmax` is a list of length `ncol(x)` and that the return value of the function `cmaxstat()` is written to position `i` of that list `mmax` (`mmax[[i]]`). The return value of `cmaxstat()` seems to be a dataframe. A column gets added to that dataframe named `data.name`.
You can just try out what such a loop does by inventing a simple example yourself!